# How can I extract web app content from html code?

Tags: java, html, web-applications, data-mining

So I'm currently trying to gather data from csgo gambling sites to analyze them. So I wrote a very short programm extracting the html code from this website but it won't extract the content of the web app.
My problem now is that I need the information within this web app. I mean I can view it in Chrome so I guess there will be solution.
Maybe the pictures help to understand what I'm looking for:

[HTML code; marked the line I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f51GN.png)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            
            String html = Jsoup.connect("https://www.wtfskins.com/crash").get().html();
            System.out.println(html);
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So that's what I get. I need the content of

```
<body> <app-root> 
  loading... // That's the problem
 </app-root> 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
 <script src="/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
 <script src="/assets/js/sha3.js"></script> 
 <script src="/assets/js/sha256.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.2b75d68d2d6cb678fc8d.bundle.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.7932c68952979c366236.bundle.js"></script>  
</body>
```

Comment: May be you can try using regular expressions to match the tags and get content between the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded in the page after the initial DOM.
When you are getting data with `JSoup`, you get the initial html request.

#### This image shows that the html request really gives kinda empty html structure

[image]
If you check the `Network` tab in the `dev tools` in the browser, you will see that after the initial load there will be extra XHR requests, getting the data.
`ngcontent` attributes of tags assure that the page is loaded using [Angular](https://angularjs.org/), which is a Javascript framework. 
This is done to make page loads more efficient and protect from the scraping a bit more.

### AFTER CHECKING

The network tab shows multiple requests after the page load that have JSON responses. You need to look at those, see which request headers are mandatory to request them.
As image shows, one of interesting ones is:
https://www.wtfskins.com/api/v1/p2ptrading/usertrades/

[image]

You can start by looking at [How the Web works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/How_the_Web_works) with subcategories about Async Javascript requests and [REST API basics](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/) as well. If you are not familiar with web dev, the research will take a bit of time.

Comment: Well first of all, thank you very much for the well written response! But I have to admit that I didn't understand it. I don't know what to do with this information. Maybe you got some threads or YT videos I could work with?

Comment: HTML GET requests are not the only ones that make a web page. Data/files are gathered during after initial load. Networks tab shows all the information about those requests that the page makes to the server. You have to replicate those which contain the data you need.

Comment: @SO_is_love I added two links to the post, but you have to research a bit more than that. If you agree that this answers your question of why your code didn' t work, feel free to accept my answer